# how to write *(star) program in angular 2+

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngfor

Write the code in Angular 2+

On click of button print * in `<ul><li></li></ul>`

For example.

Click 1 - Output is *

Click 2 - Output is **

Click 3 - Output is ***

Answer (score 1):

Just append '*' after you fired a click event:

HTML

```
<p>{{ title }}</p>

<button (click)="addStar()">Add star</button>
```

TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  title = '*';

  addStar() {
    this.title += '*';
  }
}
```

### For your reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdw4es